# Arduino Socket.io shows disconnected when delay() is used

Tags: c, socket.io, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am new to Arduino and facing an issue. I am implementing socket in Arduino for ESP8266 . It works as expected when I am not using `delay()` or not using `someFunction()`.  As soon as i use delay or do some processing than i am getting connection disconnected one server socket.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
#include <SocketIOclient.h>
#include <Hash.h>
ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
SocketIOclient socketIO;

#define USE_SERIAL Serial1

void socketIOEvent(socketIOmessageType_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
    switch(type) {
        case sIOtype_DISCONNECT:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] Disconnected!\n");
            break;
        case sIOtype_CONNECT:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] Connected to url: %s\n", payload);
            break;
        case sIOtype_EVENT:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get event: %s\n", payload);
            break;
        case sIOtype_ACK:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get ack: %u\n", length);
            hexdump(payload, length);
            break;
        case sIOtype_ERROR:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get error: %u\n", length);
            hexdump(payload, length);
            break;
        case sIOtype_BINARY_EVENT:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get binary: %u\n", length);
            hexdump(payload, length);
            break;
        case sIOtype_BINARY_ACK:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[IOc] get binary ack: %u\n", length);
            hexdump(payload, length);
            break;
    }
}

void setup() {
    // USE_SERIAL.begin(921600);
    USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);

    //Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
    USE_SERIAL.setDebugOutput(true);

    USE_SERIAL.println();
    USE_SERIAL.println();
    USE_SERIAL.println();

      for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
          USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", t);
          USE_SERIAL.flush();
          delay(1000);
      }

    // disable AP
    if(WiFi.getMode() & WIFI_AP) {
        WiFi.softAPdisconnect(true);
    }

    WiFiMulti.addAP("SSID", "passpasspass");

    //WiFi.disconnect();
    while(WiFiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(100);
    }

    String ip = WiFi.localIP().toString();
    USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] WiFi Connected %s\n", ip.c_str());

    // server address, port and URL
    socketIO.begin("10.11.100.100", 8880);

    // event handler
    socketIO.onEvent(socketIOEvent);
}

unsigned long messageTimestamp = 0;
void loop() {
    socketIO.loop();

    uint64_t now = millis();

    if(now - messageTimestamp > 2000) {
        messageTimestamp = now;

        // creat JSON message for Socket.IO (event)
        DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
        JsonArray array = doc.to<JsonArray>();

        // add evnet name
        // Hint: socket.on('event_name', ....
        array.add("event_name");

        // add payload (parameters) for the event
        JsonObject param1 = array.createNestedObject();
        param1["now"] = now;

        // JSON to String (serializion)
        String output;
        serializeJson(doc, output);

        // Send event        
        socketIO.sendEVENT(output);

        // Print JSON for debugging
        USE_SERIAL.println(output);
    }
//NEED TO DO SOME PROCESSIONG
delay(2000);
someFuntion();
}


void someFunction(){
//some processing that consume the time
}
```

Comment: Please check the default timout ,  and reduce the delay to below default timeout and see if that works

Comment: the delay is not fixed from my side because  the above code will be followed by few more function (will consume time and add a delay)  .  where should i check the default timeout? 1)server or 2)Client

Comment: you can check server side timout

Comment: @cslrnr I have one more doubt. Please tell me why are we using this IF BLOCK " if(now - messageTimestamp > 2000)" . When i am removing the code inside this block and placing it outside than again i am receiving disconnect error

Comment: This if block checks difference between some message received (I guess) in the past with current time (now) , say now in integer rep is 345123 and messageTimestamp is 344410

Comment: @cslmr, thank you for the reply. i have also concluded that if the there is a delay of more than 560ms between successive "socketIO.loop()" than i get DISCONNECTED but if the dalay is less than 560ms than it work fine  ISSUE is that , there will be some delay b/w two successive  "socketIO.loop()" bec of processing

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting timeout on server side.

When you are making `delay(10000)` esp8266 is just hanging on some loop (as a delay implementation) - any other code is not executed due this time. So when the server is not getting any data it disconnects client.

The solution (easy way) is to make a new connection every time you want to send data. In pseudocode it will look like this:

```
void loop(){
    connectToServer();
    sendData();
    Disconnect();
    delay(1000);
    SomeFunction();
}
```

Then it should work.

The more complicated method is to familiarize yourself with the concept of Events and callbacks and get rid of `delay()` function. Or try to use esp_rtos_sdk witch is asynchronous tasks concepts RTOS framework.

Have fun!

Edited:

After refreshed the code I'm able to tell more about it, so I'm editing the previous post.

The quickest way to make it work(partly) is to remove the `delay(2000)` statement - because this `If()` statement is handling sending messages in 2 seconds interval. As I see you may wan't to put this `void someFunction()` to this `if()` statement too. This will make "some processing" in 2 seconds interval.

`socketIO.loop()` is handling maintaining connection with server and sending event's to server so it has to be call as quick as plausible. In case with `delay` you are getting socket timeout and disconnection.

`void loop()` function must be shortest as plausible to maintain the connection. Probably it is 500ms or so - regarding to you experiments. So any delay's is not plausible. If you need more processing try to familiarize with event processing. The easiest way is to declare flags as Boolean and timers counting time intervals. When timer is lunched it's sets the flag as true and you may process function.

Websockets on ESP(or other embedded microprocessors) are hard for beginners because they are time dependent. You need to have short processing loop or some of asynchronous methods used.

I hope, that I help.

Comment: Thank you for your response. i am still unable to figure out where the issue is. Adding somefunction() also cause the disconnect and removing  the code outside of the IF STATEMENT BLOCK "if(now - messageTimestamp > 2000)", also cause the same issue

Comment: It would be better to paste all your code, not only `loop()` function. I don't know how you configured the websocket. For now I'm targeting timeout on server side, due the long processing of other functions in `loop`. All examples that I found in loop function call only `socketIO.loop()`.

Comment: I have one more doubt.  Please tell me why are we using  this IF BLOCK " if(now - messageTimestamp > 2000)" . When i am removing the code inside this block and placing it outside than again i am receiving disconnect error

Comment: This block is for setting message sending time period. Before `If()` block you set a variable with information on how many milliseconds have elapsed since the board was turned on and in `If()` you are setting another variable with this same value. In second loop iteration if difference between `now` and `messageTimestamp` if bigger than 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds) message will be send again. If you just remove If statement and you left the `delay()` function you will still get disconnect.

Comment: Can you tell me exact name of library that you use? I have doubt that `sendEvent()` function really send's a event. I think it yous put it on some queue and sending is made in `socketIO.loop()` - but this is a hypothesis to check it I need a name of library.

Comment: i am using  1)  WebSockets by Markus Sattler
and 2) SocketIoClient  library

Comment: Could you edit your post and paste all code from file?